# Redis: Is it still O(logN) to get top score member from sorted set?

Tags: redis

My code needs to frequently get the top score member from a sorted set of Redis.

The time complexity for zrangebyscore is O(logN): http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore.
Since I only want to get the top score one, will Redis optimize it to return top score member in O(1) time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redis documentation doesn't describe such an optimization. The page you linked to for `ZRANGEBYSCORE` states (emphasis added):

> Time complexity: **O(log(N)+M)** with N being the number of elements in
>   the sorted set and M the number of elements being returned. **If M is
>   constant** (e.g. always asking for the first 10 elements with LIMIT),
>   **you can consider it O(log(N)**).

Given this, it seems that the time complexity will not be O(1), unless of course your sorted set contains only one element. Rather, the time complexity will be dependent on the number of elements in the sorted set and will still be O(log(N)).

Comment: The full code for the `ZRANGEBYSCORE` implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/209f266cc534471daa03501b2802f08e4fca4fe6/src/t_zset.c#L2202).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the top score so frequently that ZRANGE's complexity is an issue, cache the top score independently of the sorted set and you'll be able to get to it with O(1).

Comment: That's a nice, simple solution.